# Determining the polarity of emoticons for twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis, emoticons

I am trying doing a sentiment analysis on twitter data and want to take the emoticons into account. Say I have the unicode of an emoticon  (in this case U+1F600). I would like to get some kind of positive, negative or neutral polarity score. I have done some research but have been unsuccessful in finding an existing lexicon that I could use. Basically I would like to use an existing lexicon if there is one available instead of going through all emoticons manually and assigning a score. Any suggestions?

I am using Python if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A full lexicon containing emojis and their corresponding Unicode can be downloaded from http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html .

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful:

```
pip install emosent-py
from emosent import get_emoji_sentiment_rank
get_emoji_sentiment_rank('❤')
```

https://pypi.org/project/emosent-py/